# Calling super in ApplicationController rails class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def authenticate_user!(*_args)
    super
  end
end
```

In `authenticate_user!` I call `super`, which should call `authenticate_user!` from `ActionController::Base`, which is an abstract class.

I couldn't find `authenticate_user!` inside `ActionController::Base`, so I suppose there is some meta programming involved(?).

How is that `authenticate_user!` from Devise ends up in `ActionController::Base`? Or any other method that is called by using `super` in `ApplicationController`?

Answer (score 0):

`authenticate_user!` is a method that id dynamically built by `devise`, so you have to monkey patch `devise`. Helpers are available in both controllers and views, so that's probably why you're not hitting `ActionController::Base`

If you need to override the functionality you'll need to monkey patch this class: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L148

You can override the `authenticate_user!` method by defining your own. First, you'll have to create the directory `lib/devise/controllers` and add a file called `helpers.rb`, to which you can add:

module Devise
  module Controllers
    module Helpers

```
  module ClassMethods
    def authenticate_user!
      # if something
      # do something
      # else
        super
      # end
    end
  end
```

If you aren't using `devise`, post a comment and I'll delete this answer